# Lie algebra and Lie group cohomology, reference request

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-cohomology

Who can give me a good reference (better if introductory/motivated) about Lie group cohomology, Lie algebra cohomology, and the link between the two?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the book [Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Cohomology](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/4408.html) by Anthony W. Knapp. It has many examples and is very detailed. It may be a good start for you.